# Error grabbing View Hierarchy, XCode 8.2.1: "No plist data for fetching view hierarchy"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, view-hierarchy

While trying to debug my view hierarchy, I get the following error:

```
Error:    Unable to capture view hierarchy.
Details:  No plist data for fetching view hierarchy: error evaluating expression “(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("DBGViewDebuggerSupport_iOS") fetchViewHierarchyWithOptions:(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSDictionary") dictionaryWithObjects:(id)[(id)[(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSArray") arrayWithObject:(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSNumber") numberWithBool:1]] arrayByAddingObject:(id)[(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSArray") arrayWithObject:@"_UIVisualEffectBackdropView"] arrayByAddingObject:@"_UIBackdropEffectView"]] arrayByAddingObject:(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSNumber") numberWithBool:0]] forKeys:(id)[(id)[(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSArray") arrayWithObject:@"DBGViewDebuggerUseLayersAsSnapshots"] arrayByAddingObject:@"DBGViewDebuggerEffectViewsToSnapshotAsImage"] arrayByAddingObject:@"DBGViewDebuggerAlwaysEncodeLayers"]]]”: error: Expression can't be run, because there is no JIT compiled function

Method:   -[DBGAbstractViewDescriber handleFetchedViewInfo:fetchError:resultHandler:]
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

Occured on iPhone 6 10.2 and iPhone 5C 9.3.5. XCode is 8.2.1. The Mac machine is Sierra 10.12.2 (16C67).

Reproducible always - never got it to work.

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: Issue also reported to Apple. Ticket #29814332

Comment: What's macOS version are you running?

Comment: Closed Xcode? Deleted derived data, build folder, Xcode caches, etc? Restarted Mac? Reinstalled Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

This occurred for me when running on simulator with Xcode 8.0. I was able to eliminate the bug by running on my iPhone 7 (device) running iOS 10.2.

Probably not the answer you want to hear, but you could try downloading Xcode 8.0 at the [Apple Developer downloads page.](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

Comment: I'm getting it consistently on-device.  I don't use the simulator very often (my projected is SceneKit-based, and the simulator's GL/Metal performance still isn't great).

Comment: I just run the project in another phone and it worked. I don't know why but thanks for your answer.